# How far into Brazil can I get with the completion of the Oyapock Bridge between French Guiana and Brazil?

Tags: road-trips, brazil, french-guiana

It is estimated that the [Oyapock Bridge](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Oyapock_River_Bridge) between France and Brazil will be finished in 2012. I have already been to Oyapock and ever since I dreamt to do a road trip starting in French Guyana. Looking on Google Maps, the roads from Oyapock into Brazil seem to end in the Amazon rain forest and in Macapa. While in Oyapock 5 years ago, I saw quite some cars driving around. This made me wonder if there are onward journeys possible from Macapa.

Comment: looks like there is no motivation to get it finished: http://www1.folha.uol.com.br/internacional/en/world/2015/02/1595049-brazil-abandons-bridge-built-in-partnership-with-france.shtml

Comment: @JanusTroelsen It's open now!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Agreed, Macapá is in the most deserted state of Brazil.  Being right by the mouth of the Amazon river, you run into the same problem that Oyapack suffered until the bridge - a giant expanse of water.

However, taxis for R$30 can take you 25km south-west to the town of Santana.  From there, you can can travel by boat across the river to Belém(24 hours), Santarem (40 hours, hammock R$ 125, cabin R$ 250) and Manaus(5 days) - plus some other smaller places.  From these cities you can easily get buses to travel further south.

I reckon one of my dream trips is to do this to Manaus, then to take a 6 day boat ride up the Amazon to Leticia in Colombia.  It sounds amazing!

Comment: do you have more information on those boat rides?

Comment: @JanusTroelsen not at hand, no, I just recall from when I was researching this back in 2011.  All found through google, though.

Answer (score 4):

I just came across a [video blog](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=joh5_KJkKsg) of some one doing that trip in oposite direction. So far it seems feasible by bike.